# How to close UWP app with double click back button?

Tags: navigation, win-universal-app, windows-10, back

There is a UWP application (but it will be used on mobiles). I made a back button navigation like this

```
        private void App_BackRequested1(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {          
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;         

        if (rootFrame == null)
            return;           

        // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
        // already been handled 
        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

And there are pages in app: LoginPage -> MenuPage -> *some other pages*. I want to exit from the application by double clicking back button at the Login and Menu pages. Is it possible to make something like this?

Comment: by "double clicking back button" you mean the hardware back button available on phone or you have a custom button inside the app to close the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible

- ignore the first back button click
- start measuring some time
- when the second back button click happens, know that the back button was previously clicked and ignored and check if the passed time would allow it to qualify as a double click
- if it qualifies as double click, let it propagate all the way to close your app

So, it's possible, but you may want to rethink this as I don't think that this approach is common on the platform.

Comment: Thank you! It is good solution. But i saw, that very few programms use something like that, so now I don't know, how will be better: with this method or without.